# Why does this script fail to add the value of a number-type input to an integer variable?

Tags: javascript, input, comparison

I have a form for configuring a product, and when each selection is checked it updates the total cost. Most of this is working, except for the one with a variable input - the cost of delivery varies directly with the mileage. The total value is not changing when I input a positive number and then check the box, I cannot figure out why. I should note that I had this working to some extent before, but it did not have logic to handle a negative input; when I added the comparison, it stopped working, so I think it may be failing to return True when comparing mileage >= 0.

```js
let total = 12000;
let mileage = "document.getElementById('delivery-mileage').value";

[...document.getElementsByClassName('form-check-input has-value')].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.id == "delivery"){
        if (parseInt(mileage, 10) >= 0) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
          total += parseInt(mileage, 10)
        } else {
          total -= parseInt(mileage, 10)
        }
      }
    }
      else{
        if (e.target.checked) {
          total += parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
        } else {
          total -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('total-cost').innerHTML = `$${total.toLocaleString("en-US")}.00`
  })

})


document.addEventListener('click', e=> {
  console.log(e.target);

})
```

```html
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="max-width: 1000px;">
      <input class="form-check-input has-value" type="checkbox" name="delivery" id="delivery">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="suitcase">Delivery to a distance of...<p class="price">$1/mile</p></label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="delivery-mileage" placeholder="Miles to deliver" style = "width: 200px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="max-width: 1000px;">
    <h2 id="total">Total Cost: <span id="total-cost">$12,000.00</span> plus tax</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `let mileage = "document.getElementById('delivery-mileage').value";` <-- um that is a string, not a reference to the element

Comment: `let mileage = "document.getElementById('delivery-mileage').value"` is wrong, this should be `let mileage = document.getElementById('delivery-mileage').value;
`

Comment: curiously, why are you setting the `radix` in parseInt?

Comment: @Kinglish I was trying to rule out any possible causes for the comparison failing

Comment: @Kinglish there is no harm in doing it and at one point in history, that was the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you learned to do

```
let mileage = "document.getElementById('delivery-mileage').value";
```

but all that is doing it setting mileage to a string. It is not magically refefrencing the DOM value.

You need to change it to

```
const mileageElem = document.getElementById('delivery-mileage');
```

and when you need the value, you need to read it

```
item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const mileage = mileageElem.value;
  ...
});
```

Comment: I see that I made a mistake making the mileage reference a string, but I don't understand why I cannot set mileage = xxx.value to always reference the value as that variable and instead need to get the value in the function.

Comment: because the variable holds the value at that moment in time. It does not keep updating it. It is not a reference to the property.